# Java object BigDecimal reflection to setCellValue to double?

Tags: java, excel

I have a `Person` class defined:

```
String name;
BigDecimal balance;
```

I am trying to output its info into `SXSSFWorkbook` and so far I have the following:

```
int rowIndex = 0;

List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person3)

SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle;
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));

//create sheet etc..
.
.

Field[] fields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Person person: persons) {
   Row row = sheetCreateRow(rowIndex++) 
   for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
       Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
                
       Field field = dataFields[i];
       field.setAccessible(true);
    
       Object fieldData = fields[i].get(rowData);

       // here is the trouble i am having, since setCellValue does not set for BigDecimal, 
       // I want it to set it as a double by using BigDecimal.doubleValue().
    
       cell.setCellValue(((Double)(fieldData)).doubleValue());

   }
}
```

`fieldData`is a BigDecimal type showing as i.e `100.00` and `field` is a `Field` type showing as `private java.math.BigDecimal test.project.model.Person.balance`.

If I run the method it is throwing an error saying how BigDecimal cannot be casted into a double. And so I am wondering if there is a way to actually grab that BigDecimal value and then use the BigDecimal function `doubleValue()` so we can set the cell value as a double?

Comment: Yes, that's because it can't be cast that way.  You should be doing the math with BigDecimal methods, but if you really need a double call `doubleValue()`.

Comment: Why are you reflectively accessing the fields of  `Person`? Why not add getters?

Comment: @tgdavies because we wouldn't know which fields are being accessed next and when writing to the excel we want to decide if it is of type String or double so we can set the cell value as string or double. there could be 3 different balances in a ```Person```

Comment: @markspace how do we do that? can you write it in a code? I've been scrambling my brain trying to call BigDecimal.doubleValue()

Answer (score 0):

I agree with tgdavies, your code seems overly complex and there's likely a simpler way to do this.  Maybe posting some additional code would help?

But if you just need to cast, you cast the Object to a BigDecimal (because that's what it actually is), and then you call doubleValue().

```
   Object fieldData = fields[i].get(rowData);

   // here is the trouble i am having, since setCellValue does not set for BigDecimal, 
   // I want it to set it as a double by using BigDecimal.doubleValue().

   BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) fieldData;
   double value = bd.doubleValue();

   cell.setCellValue(value);
```

Comment: Is there any safety issues to this or anything?

Comment: if `fieldData` is not `BigDecimal` you'll get an exception.  Might want to catch that.  I can't think of any other issues.